# Cryptic pom.xml errors in a GWT/Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, maven

I am a relative newcomer to the Java world from .NET, so I sometimes struggle with things that must seem obvious to experienced Java developers, but this problem has stumped even some of my grizzled co-workers.

Here's my environment:

- JavaSE 1.6
- Eclipse Indigo SP2
- m2e plugin 1.1.0.201205-30-0009
- Google Suite plugin 2.5.2
- GWT Maven plugin 2.4
- Spring 1.1

The main project uses GWT 2.4.0 and compiles and works fine by itself. I also have a custom DB logging project in the same workspace which also builds without any errors. I need to use the custom DB logging functionality in the main web app, so I add the former to the latter as a dependency using Maven, and that's where things break.

After rebuilding the workspace Eclipse shows three cryptic errors in the main project's pom.xml:

```
null (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded:default:compile) pom.xml /TestApp    line 67 Maven Build Problem
null (org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile:default:prepare-package) pom.xml /TestApp    line 44 Maven Build Problem
null (org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:generateAsync:default:generate-sources)  pom.xml /TestApp    line 44 Maven Build Problem
```

Scroll down to the end of my question to see the entire pom.xml.  The offending dependency is called `net.cds.cps.dao.logger` and can be found at the bottom of the dependency list.

When pom.xml is opened in Eclipse the two `<execution>` nodes of plugins `gwt-maven-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` are highlighted.

The usual troubleshooting steps (cleaning the projects, disabling/enabling Maven's workspace dependency resolution, updating project configuration) have no effect on the errors. Changing the dependency version from 1.0.0 to a more specific 1.0.0.43 or a more generic range [1.0.0.0, 1.0.1.0) has no effect either.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can go about troubleshooting this problem?

```
001 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
002 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
003     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
004 
005     <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
006     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
007     <groupId>net.test.app</groupId>
008     <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
009     <packaging>war</packaging>
010     <version>1.0.0</version>
011     <name>Test App</name>
012 
013     <properties>
014         <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
015         <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
016         <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
017         <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
018         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
019 
020         <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
021         <final.name>TestApp</final.name>
022     </properties>
023 
024     <build>
025         <resources>
026             <resource>
027                 <filtering>true</filtering>
028                 <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
029             </resource>
030         </resources>
031         <finalName>${final.name}</finalName>
032 
033         <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
034         <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
035 
036         <plugins>
037 
038             <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
039             <plugin>
040                 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
041                 <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
042                 <version>2.4.0</version>
043                 <executions>
044                     <execution>
045                         <goals>
046                             <goal>compile</goal>
047                             <goal>i18n</goal>
048                             <goal>generateAsync</goal>
049                         </goals>
050                     </execution>
051                 </executions>
052                 <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
053                     documentation at codehaus.org -->
054                 <configuration>
055                     <runTarget>Main.html</runTarget>
056                     <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
057                     <i18nMessagesBundle>net.cds.cps.cpcadmin.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
058                 </configuration>
059             </plugin>
060 
061             <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
062             <plugin>
063                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
064                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
065                 <version>2.1.1</version>
066                 <executions>
067                     <execution>
068                         <phase>compile</phase>
069                         <goals>
070                             <goal>exploded</goal>
071                         </goals>
072                     </execution>
073                 </executions>
074                 <configuration>
075                     <webappDirectory>
076                         ${webappDirectory}
077                     </webappDirectory>
078                 </configuration>
079             </plugin>
080 
081             <plugin>
082                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
083                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
084                 <version>2.3.2</version>
085                 <configuration>
086                     <source>1.6</source>
087                     <target>1.6</target>
088                 </configuration>
089             </plugin>
090         </plugins>
091 
092         <pluginManagement>
093             <plugins>
094                 <plugin>
095                     <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
096                     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
097                     <version>1.0.0</version>
098                     <configuration>
099                         <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
100                             <pluginExecutions>
101                                 <pluginExecution>
102                                     <pluginExecutionFilter>
103                                         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
104                                         <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
105                                         <versionRange>2.4.0</versionRange>
106                                         <goals>
107                                             <goal>resources</goal>
108                                             <goal>compile</goal>
109                                             <goal>test</goal>
110                                             <goal>i18n</goal>
111                                             <goal>generateAsync</goal>
112                                         </goals>
113                                     </pluginExecutionFilter>
114                                     <action>
115                                         <execute />
116                                     </action>
117                                 </pluginExecution>
118                                 <pluginExecution>
119                                     <pluginExecutionFilter>
120                                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
121                                         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
122                                         <versionRange>[2.1.1,)</versionRange>
123                                         <goals>
124                                             <goal>exploded</goal>
125                                         </goals>
126                                     </pluginExecutionFilter>
127                                     <action>
128                                         <execute />
129                                     </action>
130                                 </pluginExecution>
131                             </pluginExecutions>
132                         </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
133                     </configuration>
134                 </plugin>
135             </plugins>
136         </pluginManagement>
137         
138     </build>
139 
140     <dependencies>
141         
142         <!-- Google Web Toolkit Stuff -->
143         <dependency>
144             <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
145             <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
146             <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
147             <scope>runtime</scope>
148         </dependency>
149         <dependency>
150             <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
151             <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
152             <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
153             <scope>provided</scope>
154         </dependency>
155         <dependency>
156             <groupId>junit</groupId>
157             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
158             <version>4.7</version>
159             <scope>test</scope>
160         </dependency>
161         <dependency>
162             <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
163             <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
164             <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
165             <scope>test</scope>
166         </dependency>
167         <dependency>
168             <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
169             <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
170             <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
171             <classifier>sources</classifier>
172             <scope>test</scope>
173         </dependency>
174 
175         <!-- Spring -->
176         <dependency>
177             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
178             <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
179             <version>${spring.version}</version>
180         </dependency>
181         <dependency>
182             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
183             <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
184             <version>${spring.version}</version>
185         </dependency>
186         <dependency>
187             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
188             <artifactId>org.springframework.web</artifactId>
189             <version>${spring.version}</version>
190         </dependency>
191         <dependency>
192             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
193             <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
194             <version>${spring.version}</version>
195         </dependency>
196         <dependency>
197             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
198             <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
199             <version>${spring.version}</version>
200         </dependency>
201         <dependency>
202             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
203             <artifactId>org.springframework.oxm</artifactId>
204             <version>${spring.version}</version>
205         </dependency>
206         <dependency>
207             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
208             <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
209             <version>${spring.version}</version>
210         </dependency>
211 
212         <!--db -->
213         <dependency>
214             <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
215             <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
216             <version>1.2.4</version>
217         </dependency>
218         <dependency>
219             <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
220             <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
221             <version>1.0.2</version>
222         </dependency>
223         <dependency>
224             <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
225             <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
226             <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
227         </dependency>
228         <dependency>
229             <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
230             <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
231             <version>1.2.2</version>
232         </dependency>
233 
234         
235         <!-- logging -->
236 
237         <dependency>
238             <groupId>ant</groupId>
239             <artifactId>ant-apache-log4j</artifactId>
240             <version>1.6.5</version>
241         </dependency>
242 
243         <dependency>
244             <groupId>log4j</groupId>
245             <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
246             <version>1.2.16</version>
247         </dependency>
248 
249         <dependency>
250             <groupId>net.cds.cps.dao.logger</groupId>
251             <artifactId>LoggingDAO</artifactId>
252             <version>1.0.0</version>
253         </dependency>
254     </dependencies>
255 
256     <repositories>
257         <repository>
258             <id>asc.internal</id>
259             <name>Internal Repository</name>
260             <url>http://repository/maven2/internal</url>
261         </repository>
262         <repository>
263             <id>springsource-release</id>
264             <name>SpringSource Releases Repository</name>
265             <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
266         </repository>
267         <repository>
268             <id>springsource-external</id>
269             <name>SpringSource External Releases Repository</name>
270             <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
271         </repository>
272     </repositories>
273 
274     <pluginRepositories>
275         <pluginRepository>
276             <id>gwt-maven-plugins</id>
277             <url>http://gwt-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo/</url>
278         </pluginRepository>
279     </pluginRepositories>
280     
281     <distributionManagement>
282         <repository>
283             <id>internal</id>
284             <name>Internal Shared Maven Repository</name>
285             <url>scp://maven/var/www/html/maven2/internal</url>
286         </repository>
287     </distributionManagement>
288         
289 </project>
```

Comment: could you please try running the build from the command line and posting any resulting errors/traces ? try something like "mvn clean install -X"

Comment: Thank you **radai** for the suggestion. I did just as you told me and examined the output. It seemed that Maven was hitting all the external repos but not the internal one. I then noticed that the internal repo's id had a dot in it, so on a hunch I removed the dot and -- BINGO !!!  Everything now works like a charm.

So lesson for the future:  Don't try to get creative coming up with id's in pom.xml.

Comment: glad i could help. maven is essentially a command line tool, best used from the command line :-)